# (DDCL) DropDownCheckList is not working

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin found [here](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) of version 1.4

And saved it in my local machine , refering it for my HTML code from local ,and also I am using jquery of version 1.7.1 .I want to create my dropdown checklist on my page load , but it is not happening correctly , can anyone suggest that where I am going wrong and what I am doing wrong , and here is my code snippet,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="C:/Users/local/Desktop/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="C:/Users/local/Desktop/ui.dropdownchecklist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select multiple id="s2">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {        
$("#s2").dropdownchecklist();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link does not seems to be working

Comment: sorry the link is http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Answer (score 0):

[not tested]

Try prepending "file://localhost/" to your paths:

```
<script src="file://localhost/C:/Users/local/Desktop/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="file://localhost/C:/Users/local/Desktop/ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
```

You should be able to leave out the host part (localhost) like this (notice three slashes):

```
<script src="file:///C:/Users/local/Desktop/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="file:///C:/Users/local/Desktop/ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found the issue.

in ui.dropdownchecklist.js, at the end of the function "_syncSelected:function(senderCheckbox)"

make the last loop (allCheckboxes.each(function(index) {) look like this:

```
    allCheckboxes.each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")
            $(selectOptions[index]).attr("selected", "selected");
        else
            $(selectOptions[index]).removeAttr("selected");
    });
```